# Magento - get rule from coupon code

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I have to retrieve the rule associated to a coupon code in order to display in quote the discount percentage of that rule.
the simplest way is to calculate directly from quote amounts, but i want to retrieve directly the rule and then get the discount percentage from it.

this is what i tried:

```
 $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
 $rule->load($couponCode);
```

by this way i still havent retrieved rules attributes. any help?

thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To load a coupon by code, pass `'code'` as 2nd param to `load()`. Then you can get the proper rule instance by using the `rule_id` value of your coupon instance:

```
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');
$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
var_dump($oRule->getData());
```

Answer (score 3):

First get the coupon code

```
$orderNumber = 100000105; //order number with coupon code

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);

$orderDetails = $order->getData();

$couponCode = $orderDetails['coupon_code'];
```

Then use solution by Jürgen Thelen.

Answer (score 0):

May be this solution will help you to get couponcode amount by coupon code.

$couponCode = '**YOUR COUPONCODE**';

$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');

$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());

print_r($oRule->getData());exit();