# Magento get coupon description

Tags: magento, coupon

I am trying to retrive the text set in the Magento Coupon Description field to use as part of a validation rule. Does anyone know how to load a coupon price rule using the coupon code and retrieve the associated coupon description text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Magento 1.3, you can use this code (not tested as I have no 1.3 within easy reach) :

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($code, 'coupon_code');

if ($rule->getId()) {
    $description = $rule->getDescription();
}
```

Comment: It is Magento 1.3.x and there is no /Mage/SalesRule/Model/Coupon.php your example doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer for Magento 1.3 (my previous example should work for 1.4+ versions only)

Comment: Yes, salesrule/rule works for 1.3, thanks very much for the answer.

Comment: $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($code, 'coupon_code'); this will give error as unknown column error. See my answer for the same

Answer (score 2):

I have used in magento 1.9 and below code is working fine for me.

```
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');
                $oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
                $message = $oRule->getData();
                $description = $message['description'];

                $this->_getSession()->addError(
                    $this->__($description, Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode))
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');
$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
var_dump($oRule->getData());
```

you can refer for same [Magento - get rule from coupon code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531765/magento-get-rule-from-coupon-code)