# coupon code description magento on cart

Tags: magento

how do we fetch the coupon code description to the shopping cart. Currently magento shows Coupon code "test001" applied.

I am wondering how do we fetch the description we added in magento backend instead of that message.

display message like "Coupon code "test001" has been applied, you just saved $100 happy shopping."

[Magento get coupon description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025974/magento-get-coupon-description) I was looking this but it didn;t worked for me .

Comment: why that didn't work for you any error put that if not then where you trying to put that code ?

Comment: "app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php" in this file its not printing just blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .It works for me

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('code', '1234');
foreach ($rule as $value) {

    $description = $value->getDescription();
    print_r($description);

}.
```

I put this code in cart controller under the addAction() function.

Comment: I am using 1.7 ver of magento,I added the code but it did nothing

Comment: @user2328366 Write exit after the print_r() to check what it dispaly.

Answer (score 0):

codes submited by Mahmood Rehman works, even in 1.7.0.2.

change "app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php"

in  public function couponPostAction()

look for

```
      if ($couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode)) . ' '.$description
                );
            }
```

change it to

```
if ($couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                $description = '';
                try { 
                   $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('code', 'YOURCOUPONCODE');
                    foreach ($rule as $value) {
                        $description = $value->getDescription();
                    }                        
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::logException($e);
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode)) . ' '.$description
                );
```

of course this could be improved, but does the job.

Regards,