# Display the description part from shopping cart price rule when customer apply the coupon

Tags: php, magento

Can anyone please help me to display the description part from shopping cart price rule when customer apply the coupon on Magento 1.9.

This [Magento get coupon description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025974/magento-get-coupon-description#comment36732055_17026385) is not working form my version.

Comment: Can we see the code that you do have? A couple of sentences doesn't usually make a good, detailed question here. If you can expand on "not working" that is helpful too.

Comment: I mean the code from tht link is not responding in magento 9.1.. Code which i used is $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($code, 'coupon_code');

if ($rule->getId()) {
    $description = $rule->getDescription();
}

Comment: ^ In the question, please - would you edit your question? There are code formatting tools too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code **:**

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
$coupon->load($this->getQuote()->getCouponCode(), 'code');
$couponObj = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($coupon->getRuleId());
echo $couponObj->getDescription();
```

Comment: Errod came:Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_CartController::getQuote() in D:\wamp\www\Jamuna\site1\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php on line 580

Answer (score 0):

load($this->getQuote()->getCouponCode(), 'code');$couponObj = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($coupon->getRuleId());
?>getName();?>getDescription();?>