# How to get Coupon Discount Amount by Coupon code?

Tags: php, magento

I used the following code to retrieve the coupon code for the current order:

```
$Coupon_Code = $order->getCouponCode();
```

It works fine, but I want to get the discount amount for a certain coupon code, using this code:

```
$Coupon_Code = $order->getCouponCode();
            
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($Coupon_Code, 'code');
$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
var_dump($oRule->getData());
$Coupon_Discount =$Coupon_Code['Discount Amount'];
```

Comment: Did you try doing a Google search for `getCouponCode()`? I found code that would give you what you need at http://freegento.com/doc/d0/d40/_validator_8php-source.html

Comment: @Enigmativity I am new in magento , It's hard to me to check the link code

Comment: Are you saying you can't click the link or are you saying that you couldn't read the code to find where it is getting the discount amount?

Comment: Actually I checked the codes but I could not get what I need I used this line of codes : $Coupon_Discount=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order);
            $Coupon_Discount->getDiscountAmount();

Comment: Do you expect that line to give you the discount amount of the coupon or the discount applied to the particular order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento - get rule from coupon code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531765/magento-get-rule-from-coupon-code)

Comment: I edited the question but it doesn't work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work can you explain what happens and how you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the discount amount for a certain coupon code by using this:

```
$couponCode = '**YOUR COUPONCODE**';
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');
$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
print_r($oRule->getData());exit();
```

In the response you can get all of the details regarding COUPONCODE.

Comment: The coupon amount return empty:
  $oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($Coupon_Code, 'code');
           $oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
           $Coupon_Number=$oRule->getData('discount_amount');
          echo "$Coupon_Numbe";
           exit();

Comment: Thanks.! 
Can you please check your $Coupon_Code variable contain Value or NULL and if yes(Value) then check that coupon code in the admin is exist and Active?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code to get the discount amount from the order:

```
$orderNumber = 145000006; 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
$orderDetails = $order->getData();

$couponCode = $orderDetails['coupon_code'];
$discountAmt = $orderDetails['discount_amount'];
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to get the coupon amount by coupon code , this is work for me to get coupon code : $Coupon_Code = $order->getCouponCode();

Comment: okay, can you explain in details so i can do research. is it coupon amount or discount amount?